# C#: How to send Username, Time and Message via TCP to TCPListener

Tags: c#, tcp

I am pretty new to Socket programming and one of the first things I started making is a simple Terminal Chat between Server and Client. I was wondering about how you send your whole message data( Username, Time, message etc. ) via TCP connection in one go.

My first attempt was to split the Data with a `:`, then display the chunks as I want ti but I realised that it prevents the user from using colons.

Second guess was serialisation... Still not sure what's the best solution to send multiple strings in a stream.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Using such a low level technology, gives you a bunch of low level problems. There are more mature technologies that could maybe suit your situation better, like wep apis, signalr, grpc, just to name a few, although they seem like they are less efficient and a steeper learning curve, I can guarantee you to get a tcp solution robust and working the way you want will take a lot longer and likely inferior in many ways.. Not to mention there are usually templates in visual studio and many tutorials and walkthroughs to help you

Comment: To enable the user to use colons while using your separation method, you could use character escaping in your protocol. If the user types a `:`, you replace it with for example `\:` before sending. The opposite site then has to revert this procedure before showing the message.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with TheGeneral that you probably don't want to use plain sockets for most applications; however, if you are just making the chat program to learn sockets, I suggest that you serialize the data (for example using JSON).  Using `Newtonsoft.json nuget package`, you can just convert your struct or object with whatever data into a JSON and deserialize it on the other end.  There are many examples on how to do it with just a few lines of code.  Coming up with your own protocol is usually a very bad idea.  I know from experience.

For passwords, it depends on how much security you want.  Since this is just to learn socket programming and not for production, I suggest you just use a hash to send the password as plain text.  `MD5` is the easiest but it is no longer secure.  `SHA-256` is still considered secure.

If you want better security, look into using `Secure Remote Password protocol (SRP)`  or `Kerberos` protocols.

Once you learn sockets, you can try using a library like `SignalR` that natively supports authentication headers.